# Azure Active Directory returning 200 code even the email is not exist usin Graph Apie

Tags: azure, http, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I'm using Graph API in my LogicApp to check if a user exists in Azure Active Directory or not. So, when I send any email address to Azure AD through the API to check it whether the email registered or not, it returns 200 code in all cases, so that I cannot decide if the email I sent is already exist or not. Can anyone help me fixing this issue please

Comment: @vijaya how excatly

Comment: working on it and will post the solution after resolving your issue.

Comment: You’re in LogicApps, there should be an operation for that. Do a search for **Get User**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @skin, **you can directly use Get User action from Azure AD to check it whether the email registered or not**.

I have implemented the same and it is working as expected. Below are the steps,

- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Here i have taken Http request trigger.
- Next taken Get user action from Azure AD.
- Once you selected Get User action it will ask for authentication.
  [image]
- Ran the logic App by providing existing User email id and got details of user.
  [image]
- Again ran logic app by providing non existing user email id and got not found.
  [image]
  In this way you can check by using Get User action of Azure Active Directory connector in logicapps.